# Deleting data from a Azure Ad user field doesn't trigger a provisioning change in SCIM

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim2

I have Scim provisioning setup and connected to azure ad using a custom application which isn't in the marketplace. Provisioning new users and changing data on existing appears to work fine. But when I delete data from a previously synched field, I'm not seeing any change to remove this data in the scim application.

I've tried all number of combinations and checking out documentation for this as a known issue, but have come up short. Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

**Mapping**

[image: Mapping]

**Data deleted from provisioned user**

[image: Data deleted from provisioned user]

**Provisioning User on demand doesn't show any changes**

[image: Provisioning User on demand doesn't show any changes]

Comment: Just found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/223936/sending-an-empty-value-with-user-provisioning-scim.html. doesn't look like it's supported...

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [user3269662](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3269662/user3269662) for sharing the right document it will help other member who is looking for the same, currently AAD Provisioning doesn't send null/empty values in almost all cases that is the reason empty/null value of phone number is not reflecting in SCIM application.You can update the value of phone number but can not pass null value, as Microsoft found this is special type of consideration and they are working on that. For knowing about progress on this you can comment on Same MS Q&A post.

**WorkAround : You need to manually delete the attribute value from SCIM application if you set null value for any attribute of AAD**